# SOnarqube using docker and how to run it?

Tags: docker, sonarqube

i need to install SonarQube using my docker.
i tried this below code to install

```
`FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install unzip curl openjdk-7-jre-headless
RUN cd /tmp && curl -L -O 
https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.0.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/sonarqube-7.0.zip
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["chmod +x","/tmp/sonarqube-7.0/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh"]
CMD ["/sonarqube-7.0/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh","start"]`
```

its build is successful.
MY QUESTION IS:
1.how can i run it on server?

I tried "docker run -d --name *image* -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube"
but its not connecting..can anyone help me from here or do i need to change in script??

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps.

1. Modify the Dockerfile last line to: 
   `RUN echo "/sonarqube-7.0/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start" >> .bashrc`
2. Rebuild the image
3. Start a container:
   `docker run -d --name image -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube /bin/bash`

Comment: hi @TonyBoy thank u for responding...the modification build successfully, but unable to connect, same result. Can u tel me what are all the steps to be done after it is successfully build???

Comment: Please share the logs of the container that failed to start.
Command: docker logs <contianer name or ID>

Comment: its not showing anything..
can u tel me the command to start container? b92bdfee4fcd is image id

Comment: Please try this: 
docker run -d --name SonarCube01 -p 9000:9000 b92bdfee4fcd  /bin/bash

Comment: 81f88a70d167223085ca0f31863cfb3761a7c6deeccadf489ac3a66786d2a077
this is the result..
Shall i launch sonarqube in browser?or any other step need to be done?

Comment: try launching in the browser, If not able to open, check for the container logs and post them here

Comment: there is nothing showing in logs and not launching also

Comment: Ok. First try to run sonar in a normal container, (Ubuntu:14.04)
Do all the steps manually and see if it is running. 
Then try to build a image by including the successful steps in the docker file.

Comment: do u have any other code to install and run Sonarqube on ubuntu os with docker???? @TonyBoy

Comment: @Hithesh: Please try with official documentation of sonarqube.
Try n use the already available docker image and check.
https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/
https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/sonarqube/